# C language: how memory alignment happened in the stack for array

Tags: c, x86, gdb, stack, memory-alignment

all, I have a interesting question about memory alignment for array in C. My OS is 32 bit Ubuntu, I compile it with gcc -S -fno-stack-protector option.

Code:

```
char array1[5] = "aaaaa";
char array2[8];
array2[0] = 'b';
```

The assembly code:

```
pushl %ebp
move %esp, %ebp.         # esp and ebp are pointing to the same words
subl    $16, %esp        # move esp to lower 16
movl    $1633771873, -5(%ebp)       # input "aaaa"
movb    $97, -1(%ebp).              # input 'a'
movb    $98, -13(%ebp)              # input 'b'
movl    $0, %eax
leave
```

I have GDB to inspect the memory,

`%ebp` is `efe8`,

`%esp` is `efd8`,

`&buf1` is `efe3`,

`&buf2` is `efdb`.

In the GDB, I run `x/4bd 0xbfffefd8`, it shows

```
0xbfffefd8:    9  -124   4  98
```

if I run x/bd 0xbfffefd8, it shows

```
0xbfffefd8:    9
```

if I run x/bd 0xbfffefdb, it shows

```
0xbfffefd8:    98
```

So the memory looks like this

```
## high address ##
?                       efe8 <-- ebb
97  97  97  97          efe4 
0  -80  -5  97(a)       efe0
0    0   0   0          efdc
9 -124   4  98(b)       efd8 <-- esp
^            ^
|            |
efd8       efdb
```

Now my questions are:

1. why the character 'b'(98) is at `efdb`, while `%esp` is `efd8`? I think 'b' should also be at `efd8`, because it is the start of the 4-bytes word. Furthermore, if I keep filling more 'b' to `buf2` which starts from `efdb`, it can only fill 5'b', not 8. How come? And what about the '\0'?

The same thing occurred to `buf1`, it starts from `efe3`, not `efe0`. What kind of alignment is this? It does not make sense to me.

2. From the assembly code, it doesn't show 16 alignment which I saw from other place, like this,

```
andl $-16, %esp     # this aligns esp to 16 boundary
```

When will the *andl* command show and when not? It is very common so I expect to see it in every program.

From the assembly code above, I could not see the memory alignment. Is it alway true? My understanding is that the assembly code is just interpreting high level code (very readable) to not-very-readable code, but still converts the exact message, so `char[5]` is not interpreted to the way considering memory alignment. Then the memory alignment should occur in the running time. Am I right? But GDB debug shows exactly the same as assembly code. No alignment at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I get the same on my machine. That's a ***very strange*** alignment, wow.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli maybe some gcc options are needed? by default, it is -o0, no optimization. I don't know what else are needed.

Comment: Well, if you're asking why GCC puts stuff like this then I don't think there's a good answer. If you're asking how can it be made to align stuff in another way then there's an answer to that.

Comment: I try ```char buf2[8] = "bbbbbbbb"```, nothing changed, the stack looks like this

```97 97 97 97 \\98 98 98 97 \\98 98 98 98 \\ x    x   x   98
```

No alignment or padding is observed.

Comment: Char arrays don’t have any alignment requirement, so the compiler simply allocates them from top down, 5 bytes for a1 and 8 bytes for a2. It subtracts 16 from esp so that esp stays aligned, and the 3 extra bytes immediately above esp are not used. Is there a reason you expect the arrays to be aligned?

Comment: @prl thanks. why doesn't char array have alignment requirement? If it is by design, how should I reason about it?

Comment: Data is generally aligned according to its size. The size of char is 1, so its alignment requirement is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong here. **TLDR answer: char arrays are aligned to 1 byte**, the compiler is right.

Digging a bit further. On my 64-bit machine, using GCC 7 with the -m32 option, I run and debugged the same code and I got the same results:

```
(gdb) x/4bd $esp+12
0xffffcdd4:     97      97      97      97
(gdb) x/4bd $esp+8 
0xffffcdd0:     0       -48     -7      97
(gdb) x/4bd $esp+4
0xffffcdcc:     0       0       0       0
(gdb) x/4bd $esp+0 
0xffffcdc8:     41      85      85      98
```

The addresses differ, of course and that's fine. Now, let me try to explain.
First, the `$esp`, is aligned at 4 byte, as expected:

```
(gdb) p $esp
$9 = (void *) 0xffffcdc8
```

So far, so good. Now, because we know that char arrays use **1** by default as alignment, let's try to figure out what happened at compile-time. First, the compiler saw `array1[5]` and put it on the stack, but because it was 5 bytes wide it had extend it to a 2nd dword. So, the first dword is full of 'a' while just 1 byte of the 2nd dword was used. Now, `array2[8]` is placed immediately after (or before, depending on how you look things) `array1[5]`. It extends on 3 dwords, ending on the dword pointed by `$esp`.

So, we have:

```
[esp +  0] <3 bytes of garbage /* no var */>, 'b' /* array2 */,
[esp +  4] 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, /* still array2 */
[esp +  8] <3 bytes of garbage /* still array2 */>, 'a' /* array1 */,
[esp + 12] 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', /* still array1 */.
```

If you add a `char[2]` array after `array2` you'll see it using the same dword pointed by `$esp` and still have 1 byte of garbage from `$esp` to your `array3[2]`.

The compiler is absolutely allowed to do that. If you want your `char` arrays to be aligned at 4-bytes (but you need a *good* reason for that!), you have to use special compiler attributes like:

`__attribute__ ((aligned(4)))`

Comment: The “3 bytes of garbage” at esp+8 are actually part of array2. Since array2 doesn’t have an initializer, those bytes contain whatever was left there.

Comment: C11 has portable syntax for alignment, like `alignas(8) char foo[8]` (if you `#include <stdalign.h>`, otherwise `_Alignas(8)`).  You don't need GNU C `__attribute__` for this.  Also, arrays of 16 bytes or larger, or any VLA, should get 16-byte alignment, according to the i386 System V ABI.  IDK if compilers really bother to respect that for locals that don't escape.  (But yes, alignof(char) = 1 so normally there's no alignment requirement.)